# Upload file to Amazon S3 from Android using maven repository

Tags: android, maven, amazon-s3

I have tried to upload a file to Amazon S3 using a presigned url, which works. Now I would like to use the Amazon API to upload the file. For convenience I added the library using the maven repository like this:

```
dependencies{
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+@jar'
}
```

I also wrote some colde that is supposed to upload the file to the server:

```
public void uploadFileToAWS(final String presignedUrl, final MyDocument document)
    {
        String bucket = presignedUrl.substring(presignedUrl.lastIndexOf("https://")+1, presignedUrl.indexOf("."));
        String key = presignedUrl.substring(presignedUrl.indexOf(".com/") + 1, presignedUrl.indexOf(".pdf"));


        try {
            TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager();

            Upload uploader = transferManager.upload(bucket, key, new File(document.getPath()));

            double progress = 0;
            TransferProgress transferProgress = uploader.getProgress();

            while(!uploader.isDone())
            {
                progress = transferProgress.getPercentTransferred();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

However, I am never reaching the point where I can debug the code. The compiler in Android Studio gives me this error, which I do not understand how to solve:

**Error:(36, 53) error: cannot access AmazonServiceException
class file for com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException not found**

I hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I Also had to include the aws-android-sdk-core library.